# Find subsequence of $(f_m)_{m \geq 1}$ which converges at every point of $E$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $E$ = {$\frac{1}{n} : n \in \Bbb N$}. For each $m \in \Bbb N$ define $f_m : E \to \Bbb R$ by
$$f_m(x) = \begin{cases}\cos(mx)&\text{if}x\geq\frac{1}{m}\\0&\text{if} \frac{1}{m + 10} < x  < \frac{1}{m}\\x & \text{if} x \leq \frac{1}{m + 10}\end{cases}$$
Then which of the following statements is true ?

1. No subsequence of $(f_m)_{m \geq 1}$ converges at every point of $E$
2. Every subsequence of $(f_m)_{m \geq 1}$ converges at every point of $E$
3. There exist infinite many subsequence of $(f_m)_{m \geq 1}$ which converges at every point of $E$
4. There exists a  subsequence of
   $(f_m)_{m \geq 1}$ which converges to $0$ at every point of $E$

My Attempt:

By observing the above options, options 1 and 3 are opposite to each other. If option 1 is correct then option 3 not correct and vice
-versa.
Also since $1 \in E$ so $f_m(1) = 1$ which is a constant subsequence of $(f_m)_{m \geq 1}$ that is convergent. In such a way we can find infinitely many sequences of $(f_m)_{m \geq 1}$. So option 1 is wrong and option 3 is correct. How can we discard other options. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you say that $f_m(1)=1$?

Comment: I agree. Surely $f_m(1)=\cos m$?

Comment: Ohh Yes, I made a silly mistake. You are right. How to proceed it towards the correct answer.